# How to handle simultaneous actions in Reinforcement Learning

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I’m trying to use Reinforcement Learning to solve a problem that involves a ton of simultaneous actions. For example, the agent will be able to take actions that can result in a single action, like shooting, or that can result in multiple actions, like shooting while jumping while turning right while doing a karate chop, etc. When all the possible actions are combined, I end up with a huge action array, say 1 x 2000. So my LSTM network output array will have that size. Of course I’ll use a dictionary to decode the action array to apply the actions(s). So my questions are, is that action array too large? Is this the way to handle simultaneous actions? Is there any other way to do this? Feel free to link any concrete examples you have seen around. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I also have been trying to do something similar for my problem. You can check out the following papers:

1. [Exploring Multi-Action Relationship in Reinforcement Learning](http://www.lamda.nju.edu.cn/wanghan/pricai16.pdf)
2. [Imitation Learning with Concurrent Actions in 3D Games](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1803.05402.pdf)
3. [Action Branching Architectures for Deep Reinforcement Learning](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1711.08946.pdf)
4. [StarCraft II: A New Challenge for Reinforcement Learning](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1708.04782.pdf)

Comment: Thanks a bunch, OpenAi's work https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.06680.pdf is also useful but they don't go into details on how to deal with simultaneous actions. A way to go around this problem is to subdivide time steps into finer steps with the number of substeps equal to the number of simultaneous actions that could be available. This only work is you are working with your own environment and not one from Gym.